# 'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Whenever I try running `npm run build` in react, I get the following error:

> 'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have tried changing the version, ejecting, modifying the nodejs path, uninstalling and reinstalling depedencies and other possible stuff but nothing works.

This is my .JSON file

```json
{
  "name": "reminder",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "3.4.2",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "3.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "4.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.11",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "resolve": "1.15.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "2.3.8",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.6",
    "url-loader": "2.3.0",
    "webpack": "4.42.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "CI= node scripts/build.js",
    "build-win": "set CI=false&&rescripts build",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

PS: i'm kinda new to react and I use windows 10

Comment: try `npm run build-win` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**CI= node scripts/build.js** "is a valid syntax in linux OS so it bringing out the error instead of that change the scripts into this :

"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON file under scripts  for the "build" key, remove "CI=" from the value to remain with "node scripts/build.js".Also remove "build-win": "set CI=false&&rescripts build".
in the end your scripts should look like

`"scripts": { "start": "react-scripts start", "build": "CI= react-scripts build", "test": "react-scripts test", "eject": "react-scripts eject" },`
It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

go to => package.json file
"build": "CI= react-scripts build",
from that line remove CL=
or copy paste this line

"build": "react-scripts build",

Answer (score 0):

`CI= node scripts/build.js` is valid syntax on Linux but **not valid syntax on Windows**. You could use something like [Windows Subsytem For Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) if you plan on developing for or on a Linux environment.

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "CI= node scripts/build.js", // <-- This
    "build-win": "set CI=false&&rescripts build",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

install the cross-env package and add cross-env in your package JSON file
like this

```
"test:ci": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --coverage",
```

its works for me